# Loading data in a table from my WebApi using Javascript does not work

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'm using the following function to load a transaction from my Web API and insert the data into a table in my Blockchain-Explorer. I try to load the TransactionId form the QueryParameter using the window.parameter.search function but as you can see below the table remains empty. Strangely, this procedure works fine in the other parts of my BlockExplorer and the data is loaded and filled correctly, only the transaction view does not work. I marked the corresponding Part in the code below.

Thats the way it is explained in my Book:
"Listing XXXX includes the JavaScript code needed to load a transaction from the web API and insert the information into the table. The txId is taken from the query parameter in the URL and passed on to the endpoint for loading transactions. The query parameter is via the window.location attribute. search reachable. However, this attribute also contains the name of the parameter including the ? and symbol. The unnecessary characters can be removed using the substring function. In order to be able to easily assemble the required URLs, some parts are prepared using the variables transactionsHref and blocksHref."

Here you can see the Endpoint of my API reprententing the Transactions in JSON as you can see, the endpoint of the API works fine and i can access the corrensponding Transaction:
[Endpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMVV8.jpg)

And here is overwiew of the Transaction Screen including URL:
[Transaction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olhv7.png)

And here you can see the working example of the "blocks":
[Block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GN5zN.png)

```
<!--
  ~ Copyright (c) Tobias Fertig, 2018.
  -->

<html lang="de">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags-->
    <meta name="description" content="The explorer for your first blockchain">
    <meta name="author" content="Tobias Fertig">
    <meta name="keywords"
          content="ethereum, explorer, blockchain, etherchain, cryptocurrency, cryptocurrencies, bitcoin">
    <title>Block Explorer Light</title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.7/paper/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
          crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="/superagent/superagent.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button class="navbar-toggle collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar"
                    aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span
                    class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Blockchain Explorer Light</a></div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="send.html">Send Transaction</a></li>
                <!--<li><a href="/accounts">Accounts</a></li>-->
                <!--<li><a href="/tx/pending">Pending Tx</a></li>-->
            </ul>
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
                <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" id="search" type="text"
                                               placeholder="Block / Tx / Account" name="search"></div>
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" onclick="triggerSearch()">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<div id="transaction" class="container">
    <h3>Transaktion</h3>
    <table class="table">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>ID:</td>
            <td><a id="txId"
                   href="/transactions.html?txid=0x43511cada8aad33a2d7735d2108eabbb2be1a0bc754d6e6aa04d7eec53fd3ef4"></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Block ID:</td>
            <td><a id="blockId"
                   href="/blocks.html?blockid=0x0107d994eea5681e4635739197e1b3227877a19b3e7b457a811b1de1fb797edb"></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <!--<tr>-->
            <!--<td>Block number:</td>-->
            <!--<td><a href="/block/4973877">4973877</a></td>-->
        <!--</tr>-->
        <tr>
            <td>Sender:</td>
            <td>
                <a id="sender" href="/accounts.html?account=0x57e630bf2d192a515ae391113344fae17285b749"></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Empf&auml;nger:</td>
            <td>
                <a id="receiver" href="/accounts.html?account=0x48b7f91f6763a5da119f436415d609d0fbe97062"></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Menge:</td>
            <td id="amount"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Nonce:</td>
            <td id="nonce"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Geb&uuml;hr - Limit:</td>
            <td id="transactionFeeLimit"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Geb&uuml;hr - Bezahlt:</td>
            <td id="transactionFee"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Geb&uuml;hr - Basispreis:</td>
            <td id="transactionFeeBasePrice"></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<script>
    function triggerSearch() {
        var target = 'blockchain/api/' + document.getElementById('search').value;

        superagent.agent().get(target)
            .then(res => {
            if(res.body.blockHash)
        {
            location.href = 'blocks.html?blockid=' + res.body.blockHash;
        }
    else if(res.body.txId)
        {
            location.href = 'transactions.html?txid=' + res.body.txId;
        }
        else
        {
            location.href = 'explorer.html';
        }
    })
    };

    //The following part should be responsible for loading the data
    var target = '/blockchain/api/transactions/' + window.location.search.substring(6);

    var transactionsHref = "transactions.html?txid=";
    var blocksHref = "blocks.html?blockid=";
    var accountsHref = "accounts.html?account=";

    var myagent = superagent.agent();

    myagent.get(target)
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res.body);
            document.getElementById('txId').innerHTML = res.body.txId;
            document.getElementById('txId').href = transactionsHref + res.body.txId;

            document.getElementById('blockId').innerHTML = res.body.blockId;
            document.getElementById('blockId').href = blocksHref + res.body.blockId;

            document.getElementById('sender').innerHTML = res.body.sender;
            document.getElementById('sender').href = accountsHref + res.body.sender;

            document.getElementById('receiver').innerHTML = res.body.receiver;
            document.getElementById('receiver').href = accountsHref + res.body.receiver;

            document.getElementById('amount').innerHTML = res.body.amount;
            document.getElementById('nonce').innerHTML = res.body.nonce;
            document.getElementById('transactionFeeLimit').innerHTML = res.body.transactionFeeLimit;
            document.getElementById('transactionFee').innerHTML = res.body.transactionFee;
            document.getElementById('transactionFeeBasePrice').innerHTML = res.body.transactionFeeBasePrice;
    });
</script>
<style>
    #transaction {
        margin-top: 3cm;
    }
</style>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit: The transaction IDs (txID) may not match in the pictures because they are 2 different ones.
And the Blockchain itself is written in Java.